# PHP how to output dynamic image

Tags: php

I think this will be an easy answer but I just can't figure it out.

I have a script that generates a pdf using fpdf and fpdi.

If I use a normal image then the pdf generates perfectly but I am trying to use an image generated dynamically by php.

```
$bc = new PrintBarcode('DARP CODE');
$bc->drawVoucher();
$src = $bc->getVoucher();

// image
$src = $bc->getVoucher();

$pdf->Image($src, 22, 94, 100, 15);
```

This gives the error:

`FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified: Resource id #16`

If I do

```
$barcode = imagejpeg($src);
$pdf->Image($barcode, 22, 94, 100, 15);
```

presumably because the imagejpeg is actually outputting the image but the image header is set because if the jpeg header is set the image will display fine so I'm just trying to figure out the correct way of doing this.

If it's easier, I have a separate script which can generate the image, e.g. `printbarcode.php' but I don't know how to get the contents of that script into this function:

$pdf->Image($barcode, 22, 94, 100, 15);

Comment: Perhaps `$pdf->Image()` expects to get path to image?

Comment: thanks but I was hoping to use the image stream rather than having to locally store and delete the generated images all the time as each image is unique so if more than one person was using it at the time it would cause a bit of chaos

Comment: Looks like you will have to find a different PDF library then. The documentation clearly states, that you need to supply a file path or URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message I would guess that the `$pdf->Image()` function is expecting `$src` to be a path to a file.  What you are passing seems like a object.

Try saving the image to disk and loading from there.  You are almost there with `imagejpeg()` function - see docs [on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php).  Supply a path to save the file

```
imagejpeg($img, 'myfile.jpg', 90); // 90 denotes high quality
$pdf->Image('myfile.jpg', 22, 94, 100, 15);
...
unlink('myfile.jpg'); // delete after
```

or alternatively look for a function on the fpdf library that takes image resource as a parameter.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping to use the image stream to avoid saving and deleting files but I might have to use what everyone has suggested

Comment: The fpdf does not seem to support using memory stream which is a shame.  There is an addon avaiable at - http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/45/ that might do what you need.  Alternatively, you can try using the url feature to generate the image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the image handler PHP uses to manipulate the image. What you need is the actual result of the image manipulation, namely the resulting file. Use `imagejpeg($img, '/path/to/some/tmp/dir/file.jpg');` and hand the path over to your `$pdf->Image()` call. Then after creating the PDF you can safely remove the temporarily stored image, I think.

Comment: thanks but I was hoping to use the image stream rather than having to locally store and delete the generated images all the time as each image is unique so if more than one person was using it at the time it would cause a bit of chaos

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this with the help of php's GD library..

```
//Create a new image from file or URL
 $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

// Output the image
 imagejpeg($img_src);  

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($img_src);
```